# Java: Testing for an uninitialized byte

Tags: java, initialization, byte

How do I **test for an uninitialized `byte` in Java**?

This doesn't work:

```
byte b;

if (b != null) {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: You don't. If it's unitialized, you can't use it as a value. That's a language feature. Maybe you are looking for reference type variables set to `null`?

Comment: simple test: if it doesn't compile, then it was uninitialized

Comment: If it really matters that you discern if or if not it has been assigned, just use the `Byte` class with a default `null` value,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "uninitialized `byte`", as the compiler will not allow you to write code that uses an uninitialized value (note: fields that are not explicitly assigned a value are *automatically* initialized to 0/false/null).

You have a few options.

You could use a wrapper type, which can be `null`, e.g.:

```
Byte b = null;

if (b != null) {
    ...
}
```

You could use a special value, but you have to be sure it does not overlap with meaningful values:

```
byte b = -1;

if (b != -1) {
    ...
}
```

You could do a variant of the above, but with a larger type (this is how, e.g., [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) indicates EOF), so that the "magic" value *can't* be in the valid range:

```
int b = -1;

if (b != -1) {
    // then b is in [0, 255] (unsigned byte in this example)
    ...
}
```

You could store a second flag indicating initialization state:

```
boolean bInitialized = false; 
byte b = 0; // arbitrary

if (bInitialized) {
    ... 
}
```

You could also rework your application logic to avoid having to do this test in the first place which, to be honest, is the solution I recommend if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language specification says the following about [the initial value of variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> [...]
>
> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using [the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

Therefore you cannot use the value of a variable until such a value is given to it.

Also, in your example, `b` could never be `null` since it is of a primitive type and that snippet would not compile for that reason as well.

As suggested in the comments, you could use a reference type and set it to `null` to indicate a special case.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization state of local variables is known at compile time. As far as I'm aware, there's no language feature to query that state.* Furthermore, since the compiler won't allow you to read a local variable until it has been initialized, you won't have any luck doing it at runtime either.

*I guess you could kind of query it by trying to read from it and seeing if the compiler allows it. lol